# ReactJS not clearing interval properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `setInterval` that I am trying to clear on `componentWillUnmount`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    setInterval(this.refreshTime, 1000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.refreshTime);
    console.log('cleared interval');
}
```

And here is my `refreshTime` for good measure:

```
refreshTime = () => {
    this.setState({
        currentTime: this.renderCurrentTime()
    });
}
```

The `console.log` logs, but I still get the `setState` error once the component unmounts.

`warning.js?8a56:36 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component.`

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the return value of setInterval and clear that:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.refreshInterval = setInterval(this.refreshTime, 1000);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.refreshInterval);
    console.log('cleared interval');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the clearInterval in the correct way. The return value of the `setInterval` needs to be passed to the corresponding method `clearInterval` where you need to clear the interval.

```
var intervalID = setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);
clearInterval(intervalID );
```